# Execute button action only if the result from actionListener=true

Tags: jsf, button, actionlistener, jdeveloper

I am developing a simple project in JDeveloper. In the jsff page I have a button which should execute a specific action only if the result from the action listener of the button is true. Please take a look at the code:

```
<af:button text="Save" id="b1" action="finish"
           actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.saveDate.isValid}">
```

For example, if the return value of `#{pageFlowScope.saveDate.isValid}` is true, then execute `action="finish"`, otherwise do nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can throw special exception in action listener -  AbortProcessingException. Doing so you inform jsf not to call remaining action listeners/actions.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909382/2008454) answer for more details.